# How to bind to the method defined in the data source class?

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-5.0

I have a list of object that is the data source. Something like that:

```
public class DataList
{
     public List<DataItem> SomeItems;
     public void RemoveItem(DataItem item)
     {
         SomeItems.Remove(item);
     }
}
```

Very simple.
Now I have a XAML that is referenced to this data source. Something like that:

```
<layout:Accordion ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}" SelectionMode="ZeroOrMore" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeItemTemplate}">
...
```

where SomeItemTemplate template is defined in App.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeItemTemplate">
<Grid>
..
<Button Command={?} Content="Remove" CommandParameter="{Binding}">


</DataTemplate>
```

How could I bind the command to refer the DataList.RemoveItem? The idea is to pass the item to the parent class (DataList) that knows everything. I can define this method (remove) in the DataItem class itself but in this case I need to pass (in the constructor) the parent class because an item knows nothing about the parent.

Solution is found. See here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Use 
`<Button x:Name="btnDeleteItem" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using silverlight 5, you could use [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) binding:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorLevel=2}}"/>
```

The idea is to find your higher in hierarchy visual element and take it's dataContext (DataList).

Comment: Thanks. If I try your way I have the exception "{System.InvalidOperationException: AncestorType must be set when RelativeSource.Mode is set to FindAncestor.
   at System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource.System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize.EndInit()
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.SupportInitializeEndInit(IntPtr nativeTarget)}". What does it mean?

Comment: It means you need to specify the type of ancestor to look for. In your case it's Accordion. Something like this should be ok: RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:Accordion}}

Comment: Thanks, I solved this problem using <Button x:Name="btnDeleteItem" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" how is described here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) But what I don't understand why the AncestorType=UserControl works?!

Comment: You're welcome :) It's either your UserControl has the same DataContext or Accordion inherits from UserControl or the tree is somehow being walked over by the runtime in search of inherited members with dataContext not null.